# Pipe output from command in Git Bash to Powershell script on windows

Tags: windows, bash, git, powershell

I am on windows in a git bash hook script and want to pipe output from a git command to a powershell script, but can not get to work in bash what otherwise works in a windows command shell:

The command in question is the following:

```
dir | powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command "$Input | send_mail.ps1"
```

Here is the content of send_mail.ps1:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param
(
[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
[string[]]$Lines
)
BEGIN
{
  $AllLines = ""
}
PROCESS
{
  foreach ($line in $Lines)
  {
    $AllLines += $line
    $AllLines += "`r`n"
  }
}
END
{
  $EmailFrom = "from@sample.com"
  $EmailTo = "to@sample.com"

  $Subject = "Message from GIT"
  $Body = $AllLines

  $SMTPServer = "smtp.sample.com"
  $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
  $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
  $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("from@sample.com", "asdf1234");
  $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
}
```

If the command is run from powershell or windows command line i successfully receive an email with the contents of the directory.

If the command is run from bash the following error is displayed:

```
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:2
+  | C:\Temp\Test\send_mail.ps1
+  ~
Ein leeres Pipeelement ist nicht zulässig.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement
```

This translates roughly to "An empty pipe element is not allowed" and means $Input is empty here. Does anyone have a working example for bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash is probably expanding the `$Input` in double quotes to an empty string, because `Input` probably isn't defined as a variable in Bash, so PowerShell gets the command  `| send_mail.ps1`.  One way to fix it is to use single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
dir | powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command '$Input | send_mail.ps1'
```

Comment: Yeah that happens when you don't know this stuff inside out and piece together information from various sites. Works like a charm now!